# Google Identity Platform - Sharing users between GCP projects (SSO)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, single-sign-on, google-identity

Is it possible to share users with the **email/password provider** across different GCP projects? We would like to offer our customers a unified login experience to all apps (which reside in [different GCP projects](https://cloud.google.com/docs/enterprise/best-practices-for-enterprise-organizations#project-structure)).

Right now we are using [Azure AD B2C](https://azure.microsoft.com/it-it/services/active-directory/external-identities/b2c/) for that, but are looking for alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.google.com/identity

Checkout google identity, which is independent from the projects.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Identity as your IdP supports the OpenID Connect (OIDC) and Security Assertion Markup Language 2.0 (SAML) protocols to enable users with SSO-based access to specified cloud apps.

SAML apps abound in Cloud Identity's app store. OIDC apps are available in the G Suite Marketplace for G Suite subscribers. While the majority of cloud apps support only one of these protocols, a select number does.

You can also review the [enable SSO for Cloud Apps documentation.](https://cloud.google.com/identity/solutions/enable-sso)

Additional documentation of [signing in users with SAML.](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/saml)